# matlab: simple matrix filtering - group size

Tags: matlab, sorting, matrix, filtering

I have a huuuge matrix storing information about X and Y coordinates of multiple particle trajectories , which in simplified version looks like that:

col 1- track number; col 2- frame number; col 2- coordinate X; col 3- coordinate Y

for example:

```
A = 
1   1   5.14832 3.36128
1   2   5.02768 3.60944
1   3   4.85856 3.81616
1   4   5.17424 4.08384
2   1   2.02928 18.47536
2   2   2.064   18.5464
3   1   8.19648 5.31056
3   2   8.04848 5.33568
3   3   7.82016 5.29088
3   4   7.80464 5.31632
3   5   7.68256 5.4624
3   6   7.62592 5.572
```

Now I want to filter out trajectories shorter than lets say 4 and keep remaining stuff like (note renumbering of trajectories):

```
B = 

1   1   5.14832 3.36128
1   2   5.02768 3.60944
1   3   4.85856 3.81616
1   4   5.17424 4.08384
2   1   8.19648 5.31056
2   2   8.04848 5.33568
2   3   7.82016 5.29088
2   4   7.80464 5.31632
2   5   7.68256 5.4624
2   6   7.62592 5.572
```

How to do it efficiently? I can think about some ideas using for loop and vertcat, but its the slowest solution ever :/

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean trajectories shorter than 2?

Comment: oh sorry, stupid me :) Of course, shorter than f.ex. 4 = trajectory from less than 4frames

Comment: this matrix is a very inefficient way of storing that information. even if you just would split it and store the "small" matrices in a cell such "filtering" of results would be trivial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will filter out those trajectories of length less than 4:

```
[v, u1, w] = unique(A(:, 1), 'last');
[~, u2, ~] = unique(A(:, 1), 'first');
keys = v(find(u1 - u2 >= 3));
B = A(ismember(A(:, 1), keys), :);
```

This will re-number them:

```
[~, ~, B(:, 1)] = unique(B(:, 1));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a slightly different solution than that of [@Ansari](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10844863/97160):

```
t = 1:max(A(:,1));                  %# possible track numbers
tt = t( histc(A(:,1),t) >= 4 );     %# tracks with >= 4 frames
B = A(ismember(A(:,1),tt),:);       %# filter rows
[~,~,B(:,1)] = unique(B(:,1));      %# renumber track numbers
```

---

Another way to compute the indices variable `tt` in my code above:

```
tt = find( accumarray(A(:,1), 1, [], @(x)numel(x)>=4) );
```